# string to int array in objective

Tags: objective-c, arrays, string

Hi I trying to convert string to int array in objective C its running fine in xcode but give some error in editor   http://ideone.com

I have input like = {1,2,3,4,5} and want to convert it into int array or NSARRAY in and print....

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

NSArray* sampleMethod(NSString*val){
    NSString *stringWithoutbracketstart = [val stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"{" withString:@""];
    NSString *stringWithoutbracketend = [stringWithoutbracketstart
    stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"}" withString:@""];
    NSLog(@"%@",stringWithoutbracketend);
    NSArray *items=[[NSArray alloc]init];
    items = [stringWithoutbracketend componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    //NSLog(@"%@",items);
return items;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSString *value =@"{1,2,3}";
    NSArray* ip1= sampleMethod(value);
    NSLog(@"%@",ip1);
[pool drain];
return 0;

}
```

Comment: That example is in Java?!?

Comment: I'm confused why does that link you have supplied link out to some java code but your question is asking about objective-c?

Comment: @trojanfoe its belong to Objective C

Comment: So why post a link to ideone.com containing java code?  Also where does that input string come from?  Would it be from `[NSArray description]` or JSON by any chance?

Comment: @trojanfoe friend its a online editor just select language objective cand try this code....

Comment: Where does that input string come from?

Comment: @trojanfoe  I need to read input from command line but here i am reading from NSString *value =@"{1,2,3}"; i want to convert it into NSARRAY ot int array...

Comment: This code snippet runs just fine... The problem is related to ideone for sure. Also please note that `NSArray` can only hold objects (so you cannot have an "int array" as per your question title) so I guess you could convert to `NSNumbers` first and then get the int values out of them after accessing the elements

Comment: @NirbhavGupta If it belongs to objective-c why does that link go out to java that is all that confuses me seems pointless if it is about objective-c

Comment: you need to select language objective c .the link which is shared was the online editor .......

Answer (score 1):

Why not make the input string valid JSON and then it can be arbitrarily extended with little coding effort (no effort at all with respect to parsing):

```
int main(int argc, const char **argv)
{
    int retval = 0;
    @autoreleasepool {
        if (argc == 2) {
            NSString *str = @(argv[1]);
            NSData *data = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSError *error = nil;
            NSArray *array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                             options:0
                                                               error:&error];
            if ([array isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
                // Done
            } else if (!array) {
                NSLog(@"Input data is invalid: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                retval = 2;
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Input data is invalid");
                retval = 3;
            }
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Provide a JSON-list");
            retval = 1;
        }
    }
    return retval;
}
```

This means you would need to supply the list in JSON format:

```
$ ./myprog '[ 1, 2, 3 ]'
```

(quotes are necessary)

Comment: @NirbhavGupta I don't understand what you mean.

Answer (score -2):

I found the solution easily by using your advice....

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

NSArray*sampleMethod(NSString*val){
    NSString *newStr = [val substringFromIndex:1];
    NSString *newStr1 = [newStr substringToIndex:[newStr length]-1];
    NSArray *yourWords = [newStr1 componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
return yourWords;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
        NSString *value =@"{1,2,3}";
        NSArray* ip1= sampleMethod(value);
        NSLog(@"%@",ip1);
    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```